# Shuffling two 2D tensors in PyTorch and maintaining same order correlation

Tags: python, pytorch, 2d, tensor

Is it possible to shuffle two 2D tensors in PyTorch by their rows, but maintain the same order for both? I know you can shuffle a 2D tensor by rows with the following code:

```
a=a[torch.randperm(a.size()[0])]
```

To elaborate:
If I had 2 tensors

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

b = torch.tensor([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
            [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
            [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

And ran them through some function/block of code to shuffle randomly but maintain correlation and produce something like the following

```
a = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

b = torch.tensor([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
            [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

My current solution is converting to a list, using the random.shuffle() function like below.

```
a_list = a.tolist()
b_list = b.tolist()
temp_list = list(zip(a_list , b_list ))
random.shuffle(temp_list) # Shuffle
a_temp, b_temp = zip(*temp_list)
a_list, b_list = list(a_temp), list(b_temp)
            
# Convert back to tensors
a = torch.tensor(a_list)
b = torch.tensor(b_list)
```

This takes quite a while and was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function `torch.randperm` to get a set of indices that act as a random permutation. The following is a small example of getting a random permutation, then applying it to both the `a` and `b` tensors:

```py
indices = torch.randperm(a.size()[0])
a=a[indices]
b=b[indices]
```